# How to set Custom View as Default View for SharePoint List?

Tags: c#, list, sharepoint, listview, sharepoint-2010

I Have Created 2 View for List now i want to set the Different view as default on different Login.
I want to do this using c# code

**For Example:**

Views are as Following:

1. AllItems
2. UserView

Then

If Admin Log in then List's Default View is AllItems

If User Log in then List's Default View is UserView

How Can I do this using C# code?

**Code Snippet:**

```
                SPUser LoggedInUser = web.CurrentUser;

                SPList CurrentList = web.Lists[ListName];

                if (LoggedInUser.LoginName == LoginUser)
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    CurrentList.Views[AllItems].DefaultView = false;
                    CurrentList.Views[UserView].DefaultView = true;
                    CurrentList.Update();              // Error here
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

                }
                else if (LoggedInUser.LoginName == LoginAdmin)
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    CurrentList.Views[AllItems].DefaultView = true;
                    CurrentList.Views[UserView].DefaultView = false;
                    CurrentList.Update();               // Error here
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
```

Above Code is Give the **Error** : "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call Update method on SPView object too.

```
SPView yourView = CurrentList.Views[UserView];
yourView.DefaultView = true;
yourView.Update();
```

Answer (score 2):

I keep this method in my extension methods

```
public static void SetAsDefaultView(this SPList self, string viewName)
    {
        if (!self.Views[viewName].DefaultView)
        {
            self.DefaultView.DefaultView = false;
            self.Views[viewName].DefaultView = true;
            self.Update();
        }
    }
```